# DataGridTextColumn - Displaying upto a maximum of three lines of text

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle as follows:

```
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="2" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

I will need a cell in this column to display text in multiple lines but the number of lines should not exceed 3. The `TextBlock` does not have a `MaxLines` property so I cannot specify it directly. What's more the `TextBlock` does not have a Template property so I can't use a border less, read-only `TextBox` either. What can I do here?

Comment: Interresting problem. What do you want to do if the user enters a text that takes more than 3 lines ? Ellipsis ?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But the idea is to keep a single row from taking up the entire visible space as the `DataGrid` itself has a limited height.

Comment: I really don't want to limit `TextBlock` height by calculating the height of 3 lines of text. :)

Comment: Haha you got me :D Well that would have been a really simple way to implement it. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think the most simple way to achieve this is to use a TemplateColumn. Here is a quick sample : Second Column is a TextColumn where you can't do much, first column is a TemplateColumn with a TextBox that will be borderless and readonly, and MaxLines set to 3 :

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Template Column" Width="30" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MaxLines="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White">
                        <TextBox.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="2" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </TextBox.Background>
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text Column" Binding="{Binding}" Width="30" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="2" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <sys:String>coucouuuuuuuuuuuuu</sys:String>

</DataGrid>
```